# Wordpress - make a list af specific users

Tags: wordpress, directory-listing

I'm working on a premiumpress theme where i have differents users type ( members, escorts, agencies ). I'd like to make a page for each category with a listing of these users. I don't know where to start. Where can i find the slug for this categories? It should be the starting point.

Answer (score 0):

first you must use:

```
<ul>
 <?php wp_list_authors('exclude_admin=0&hide_empty=0'); ?>
</ul>
```

then create thede files in your template:

In the case of authors, the hierarchy is fairly simple. The Template Hierarchy specifies that WordPress uses the first Template file it finds in your current Theme's directory from the following list:

```
1- author-{nicename}.php - If the author's nice name were rami, WordPress would look for author-rami.php.
2- author-{id}.php - If the author's ID were 6, WordPress would look for author-6.php.
3- author.php
4- archive.php
5- index.php
```